# Newton Raphson method for implicit methods

Tags: numerical-methods, implicit-differentiation

If $x'=\sqrt x$, to solve for implicit midpoint's method, which according to Wikipedia is,
$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+hf((x_{n+1}+x_{n})/2)$ for an autonomous system, where h is the time step, how can i use newton's method to calculate $x_{n+1}$? I did the following method,
$g(x_{n+1})=x_{n+1}-x_{n}-hf((x_{n+1}+x_{n})/2) $ and $g'(x)=\frac{g_{x+h}-g_{x}}{h}$, where $h$ is the time step. Now how can i get $x_{n+1}$? Should i use any explicit schemes or is there any other way?

Comment: Find the zero of $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have first to decide what you want to take as variable, $x_{n+1}$, $k$ in $x_{n+1}=x_n+hk$ or the midpoint $u=\frac{x_n+x_{n+1}}2$.

IMO the midpoint gives the easiest-to-read formulas. So use $x_{n+1}=2u-x_n$ to transform the implicit equation for $x_{n+1}$ into
$$
2u-x_n=x_n+hf(u)\iff 0=2u-2x_n-hf(u)
$$
The derivative of that equation is 
$$
2-hf'(u)
$$
so that you get the Newton step
$$
u_+=u-(2-hf'(u))^{-1}(2u-2x_n-hf(u))
$$
which you have to iterate until convergence in a numerical sense. Then set $x_{n+1}=2u-x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

First consider that
$$
x_{n + 1}  + x_n  = \left( {x_{n + 1}  - x_n } \right) + 2x_n 
$$
Then consider that in "simple words" the essential of Newton-Raphson Method
is to fix an estimate of the root $x_0$, 
replace $f(x)$ with the first terms (const+first+ eventually 2nd ..) of its Taylor expansion around $x_0$
, compute therefrom the root $x=x_1$ therefrom, restart with $x_1$ ...
Of course all subject to the criteria ensuring for convergence.

So in your case we have that:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \Delta x_n  = x_{n + 1}  - x_n  = h\,f\left( {\left( {x_{n + 1}  + x_n } \right)/2} \right) = h\,f\left( {x_n  + \Delta x_n /2} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = h\,\left( {f\left( {x_n } \right) + f'\left( {x_n } \right)\Delta x_n /2 +  \cdots } \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
*----- amended as per LutzL comment  -----*

Now we should solve for $\Delta \,x_{\,n}$, keeping firm $x_n$, from
$$
\Delta \,x_{\,n}  = h\,f\left( {x_{\,n}  + \Delta \,x_{\,n} /2} \right)
$$
and for that you can use the Newton method, starting
$$
 \begin{gathered}
  {\Delta \,^{(0)} x_{\,n}} _\,  = h\,\left( {f\left( {x_{\,n} } \right) + f'\left( {x_{\,n} } \right){\Delta \,^{(0)} x_{\,n} /2}} \right) \hfill \\
{\Delta \,^{(1)} x_{\,n}} _\,  = h\,\left( {f\left( {x_{\,n}  + {\Delta ^{(0)} \,x_{\,n}} /2} \right) + f'\left( {x_{\,n}  + {\Delta ^{(0)} \,x_{\,n}} /2} \right){\Delta \,^{(1)} x_{\,n}} /2} \right)\hfill \\
\quad  \vdots 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and stopping when the result is sufficiently accurate.

From the $\Delta \,x_{\,n}$ so found, you can get $x_{n+1}$ and reiterate the procedure

Comment: This only gives you only the first step of the Newton iteration. Which is essentially how the elementary Rosenbrock methods are derived.

Comment: @LutzL "..only the first step of.." : do not get your point. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: You have linearized the equation and solved the linearization. That is one step of Newton's method. Now you have to repeat the step starting with a linearization at the newly found approximation. This you do not do, you continue the integration with the first approximation.

Comment: @LutzL "you continue .. with the first approximation" : of course not ! Where did you get that ? what I wrote is:  *solve the above for $\Delta x_n$, get $x_{n+1}$, restart with $\Delta x_{n+1}$* which means (see the formula) that now you use the Taylor approximation around **$x_{n+1}$**. In the formula in my post, is that not clear that if you change $n$ to $n+1$ you also change $f\left( {x_n } \right) $ to $f\left( {x_{n+1} } \right) $ and so for the rest ?

Comment: As I read it, $Δx_{n+1}=x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}$ serves as the update for the next integration step, not the next Newton iteration. If so, you have one Newton iteration per integration step, not a fully converged Newton iteration.

Comment: @LutzL.. oops, maybe I understand you now: I was going to find the zero of g(x) thinking that $x_n$ is representing the approximation steps, while re-reading better the post it seems  they represent steps in TIME! sorry, I will delete my answer. Thanks indeed for signalling and for the patience in replying